# match two files based on one column with duplicate names

Tags: r

I have specified two vector in R : dif and df2

dif

```
            TX_NAME   baseMean log2FoldChange    lfcSE      stat       pvalue
1  ENSMUST00000189941.1 2924.12770      -11.52662 1.225415 -9.406295 5.139318e-21
2  ENSMUST00000174759.7   87.20515      -22.23962 2.848984 -7.806160 5.895654e-15
3  ENSMUST00000202220.3 1858.64629      -13.83620 1.769124 -7.820928 5.243522e-15
4 ENSMUST00000064151.12   81.87098      -22.15462 2.849401 -7.775185 7.533750e-15
5  ENSMUST00000139264.1  100.04720      -22.42838 2.851911 -7.864335 3.710619e-15
6  ENSMUST00000080115.9   84.68359      -22.20991 2.848771 -7.796313 6.374197e-15
          padj
1 6.380052e-16
2 8.319140e-11
3 8.319140e-11
4 8.319140e-11
5 8.319140e-11
6 8.319140e-11
```

and

df2

```
TX_NAME          NAME                    
1: ENSMUST00000193812.1 RP23-271O17.1                  
2: ENSMUST00000082908.1       Gm26206                
3: ENSMUST00000162897.1          Xkr4 
4: ENSMUST00000159265.1          Xkr4 
5: ENSMUST00000070533.4          Xkr4       
6: ENSMUST00000192857.1 RP23-317L18.1
```

I don't know how to match them based on TX_NAME and NAME, and have dif with TX_NAME and it's related NAME from df2 I can't merge them because NAME in df2 has duplicates

Comment: have you tried `merge(df, df2, "TX_NAME")`?

Comment: I'm not sure why having duplicates would prevent your from merging. What exactly is the output you desire? Also, it's better to share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I was confused cause the order of TX_NAME after merge was not same. but with your command seems it's Ok now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more detailed discussion about data frame merge is made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right). If you want to check the documentation, access [Merging Data](https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html) or [Merge Two Data Frames](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html).

So, you can make the merge as:

```
merge(dif, df2, by="TX_NAME")
```

But, you will lost the lines that doesn't appear in both data frame. So, if you want fill the blank cells with NA, you can use it:

```
merge(dif, df2, by="TX_NAME", all=TRUE)
```

Good work!